# Custom build Android app from command line

Tags: android, ant, command-line, build, apk

I'm trying to make a batch file with some commands, so once it runs, it will change some strings in the files, build the project and generate the APK signed.
The strings I need to change are:
- The package name (com.company.project)
- Some images (like icons, splash screen, ...)
- some irrelevant string that are specific from the app.

For the last 2 things I know how to do it, but for the package name I feel there is something wrong about just find and replace all the occurrences of that string in the root folder of the app (including subdirectories).

Is there any way or command that `ant` has for doing this?

Also I ran into an issue while running the command `ant release`.
I went to my root folder, ran the command and it gets errors.
So I had to go to eclipse, clean the project and let it autobuild (with no generation of APK since it does that when you try to run it on a device) so at that point my bin folder just contains the folders: classes, dexedLibs, res and the Manifest.xml file.

Then I can go to the CL and run `ant release`.
So is there any way to do all this from CL? Something like clean and build so I can run `ant release` command after with no issues?

NOTE: for `find and replace` I use an .exe called [FNR](http://findandreplace.codeplex.com/) that does the job

**EDIT:**
I'm now using gradle and can build changing the package name but there is still a few things I want to do in the build.gradle file and can't make it work.

This is build.gradle:

```
task("hello"){
  println "Hello world!!"
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

        productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            packageName "com.testCompany.testProject"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
          release {
              storeFile file("keystore/android.keystore")
              storePassword 'blah blah'
              keyAlias "blah blah"
              keyPassword 'blah blah blah'
         }
     }

     buildTypes {
        flavor1 {
            zipAlign true
            sourceSets {
                main {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                    java.srcDirs = ['src']
                    resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                    aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                    renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                    res.srcDirs = ['res']
                    assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I am pretty sure I'm doing things wrong.
So I want to:
- Change some strings in the res/strings.xml file.
- Change the icon/png files in the res/drawable.... folder for custom ones.

I have completely no idea of how to do it. I tried:

```
buildTypes{
    flavor1{
        copy{
            from('src/res/'){
             include '**/*.xml'
             filter{String line -> line.replaceAll(string_to_be_replaced, replaced_string)}
            }
            into '$buildDir/res'
        }
    }
}
```

but nothing

Comment: Nobody should be writing new custom Ant scripts at this point. Please move to Gradle for Android. Not only is this the supported command-line build system going forward, but it also handles everything that you are looking for, via product flavors.

Comment: Ok, now I have graddle, how do I set those values ? In the build.gradle file? how? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The strings I need to change are: - The package name (com.company.project)

If you are changing these things based upon whether this is a debug build or a release build, you can [specify a suffix on the package name for a build type](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types):

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you are changing these things for anything else, you can [create product flavors and replace the package name per flavor](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors):

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            packageName "com.example.flavor1"
        }

        flavor2 {
            packageName "com.example.flavor2"
        }
    }
}
```

> - Some images (like icons, splash screen, ...) - some irrelevant string that are specific from the app.

You can create source sets for build types (e.g., `src/debug/`) or product flavors (e.g., `src/flavor1/`) and have replacement versions of resources in them. That will handle your images, as well as your "irrelevant string" if you define it as a string resource.

Source sets can also have Java code, though that gets incrementally more complex, so I would recommend that you use the string resources and replacement resources instead.

Comment: `gradle build` creates the files, but when I check the apk generated, all files are correct but my src files...are not even there!

Comment: @AnnArbor87: Java source is never in the APK. That's been true since Android 1.0, and for all build systems. `classes.dex` will contain the DEX bytecode from your Java source.